# Как правильно прибавлять целочисленные значения: печатать в консоль числа в таком виде: 000 001 002

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо сделать цикл, который будет постоянно складывать с единицей и печатать в консоль числа в таком виде:
000
001
002
003
...
011
012
013
...
101
102
и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выводит таким образом числа от 000 до 999 включительно с новой строки:

```
for i in range(1000):
    print(str(i).zfill(3))
```

Или через пробел:

```
for i in range(1000):
    print(str(i).zfill(3), end=' ')
```

Функция str.zfill(3) дополняет строку str до 3-х знаков, заполняя слева нулями.

Answer (score 3):

Можно же проще гораздо:

```
for i in range(1000)
   print('{:03d}'.format(i))
   # print('%03d' % i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы печатать числа на одной и той же строке c паузой:

```
import time

for i in range(1000):
    print('\r%03d' % i, end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Связанный вопрос: [Text Progress Bar in the Console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3173320/4279)